Worship and Wandering
This is part 67 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
This is a direction-agnostic cryptic crossword. Instead of writing top-down, left-to-right like normally, answers may be entered in any direction. The numbered arrows only indicate the space reserved for the numbered answer; that answer can still go into that space backwards or forwards regardless of the arrow’s direction. Additionally, the wordplay part of some clues gives the answer spelt backwards (for example, if the answer is PLATE the wordplay might produce ETALP). Again, this does not indicate that the answer must be written in that direction in the grid.
Twelve clues are missing one letter, which must be restored before solving. Count the position of the word with the missing letter in the clue and highlight one letter of the answer at the same position in the grid (when read the right way around). For example, if the missing letter is in the fourth word of the clue, highlight the fourth letter of the answer. If the answer is PLATE, the fourth letter is T regardless of whether the wordplay gives PLATE or ETALP and regardless of which way the word is written in the grid. I hope that makes sense!
Today I have visited a large place of worship that’s a popular pilgrimage destination, and wandered directionlessly around the surrounding area. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Solve on Penpa+
1. Degree lot by Alec Guinness? (3)
2. Solitary auditor's debt (4)
3. Alley that's overgrowing will be mown at last (4)
4. Inquisitive boxer Mike has head scratched (4)
5. Predator without large fangs at the front (4)
6. Demise of everyone, bar none (4)
7. Perform aria, maybe about Mr Cummings being not blind (6)
8. Civil War leader captures tip of Long Island (4)
9. Vocalist associated with Lash called out for car part (4)
10. Peace's disturbed in flight (6)
11. One often unseen island near New Jersey, in North America (5)
12. One turn sine (3)
13. Relax with visitor from far away, getting a kind of gift? (6)
14. Highlight in Panama: Three boarding ship (6)
15. Slowly, bid with excellent night vision gets evaded – that's sneaky (3)
16. Poe my crypt at regular intervals (3)
17. Year starting in earnest with University of Queensland quiz (5)
18. Each woman first made to stand next to railway (5)
19. Cheerful spirit of rand master in Jeet Kune Do? (4)
20. Medium perhaps gives frustrated response out loud (4)
21. 33 Sparrow's first exercise at the gym? (6)
22. Oscar wears the Oman's clothing (4)
23. Feel government keeping eye (4)
24. In our vicinity, The Star-Child narrated (3)
25. Gaping opening remains, showing serious injuries (6)
26. My bad parody ends too soon (4)
27. Milk producers in the West (4)
28. Hard rock group that's French? (4)
29. Happened upon one thin (4)
30. Atari settlement described in quote from Homer, with prelude from Aeschylus (4)
31. Messy pace in myth, essentially edge of Hades (3)
32. When the Ride Month is celebrated, perhaps by displaying rainbow flags (and, originally, English navy's Union 33) (4)
33. Raise flag (4)

Gladys will return in Tombs of Ancients.

Gladys is ...

 .. at the Golden Temple in Amritsar, India.

The grid:

 

The clues:

 (The missing letters are indicated in square brackets in the clues. The explanations are in "cryptic shorthand" of some sort. A reversal indicator on the answer means that the clue is silently reversed as per the instructions.)

 1.  Degree lo[s]t by Alec Guinness? (3)
         ALE = ALE(c)

 2.  Solitary auditor's debt (4)
         LONE, sounds like loan

 3.  [V]alley that's overgrowing will be mown at last (4)
         GLEN = (overgrowin)G (wil)L (b)E (mow)N

 4.  Inquisitive boxer Mike has head scratched (4)
         NOSY< = (t)YSON

 5.  Predator without large fangs at the front (4)
         WOLF = W/O + L + F(angs)

 6.  Demise of everyone, bar none (4)
         FALL = (o)F ALL, where (o) is none, zero

 7.  Perform aria, maybe about Mr Cummings being not blind (6)
         SEEING = EE (Cummings) in S.ING

 8.  Civil War leader captures tip of Long Island (4)
         ELBA< = L(ong) in AB.E (Lincoln)

 9.  Vocalist associated with [S]lash called out for car part (4)
         AXLE sound like Axl (Rose)

 10. Peace's disturbed in flight (6)
         ESCAPE = PEACES*

 11. One often unseen island near New Jersey, in North America (5)
         NINJA = (I + NJ) in N.A

 12. One turn sin[c]e (3)
         AGO = A + GO

 13. Relax with visitor from far away, getting a kind of gift? (6)
         BASKET = BASK + E.T.

 14. Highlight in Panama: Three boarding ship (6)
         STRESS = TRES (three in Spanish as spoken in Panama) in S.S

 15. Slowly, bi[r]d with excellent night vision gets evaded - that's sneaky (3)
         SLY = SL(owl)Y

 16. Po[k]e my crypt at regular intervals (3)
         PRY< = (m)Y (c)R(y)P(t)

 17. Year starting in earnest with University of Queensland quiz (5)
         QUERY< = YR + E(arnest) + UQ

 18. Each woman first made to stand next to railway (5)
         EVERY = EVE (woman first made) + RY

 19. Cheerful spirit of [G]rand master in Jeet Kune Do? (4)
         GLEE = G (Grand) + (Bruce) LEE

 20. Medium perhaps gives frustrated response out loud (4)
         SIZE, sounds like sighs

 21. 33 Sparrow's first exercise at the gym? (6)
         SQUATS = SQUAT (nothing, "jack", answer to 33) + S(parrow)

 22. Oscar wears the [w]oman's clothing (4)
         SHOE = O in SH.E

 23. Feel government keeping eye (4)
         OGLE<, hidden in fe(EL GO)vernment

 24. In our vicinity, The Star-Child narrated (3)
         SUN, sounds like son

 25. Gaping opening remains, showing serious injuries (6)
         GASHES = G(aping) + ASHES

 26. My bad parody ends too soon (4)
         OOPS< = SPOO(f)

 27. Milk producers in the West (4)
         EWES, hidden in th(E WES)t

 28. Hard rock group that's French? (4)
         KISS, cryptic def. alluding to a French kiss

 29. Happened upon one thin[g] (4)
         ITEM< = MET + I

 30. [Q]atari settlement described in quote from Homer, with prelude from Aeschylus (4)
         DOHA = D'OH + A(eschylus)

 31. Messy p[L]ace in myth, essentially edge of Hades (3)
         STY< = (m)YT(h) + (hade)S

 32. When the [P]ride Month is celebrated, perhaps by displaying rainbow flags (and, originally, English navy's Union 33) (4)
         JUNE< = E(nglish) N(avy's) U(nions) J(ack, answer to 33)

 33. Raise flag (4)
         JACK, double def.


Nice work! Rot13(32 qbrf unir jbeqcynl naq va 21 V guvax lbh zvtug or ybbxvat ng gur jebat raq bs gur pyhr. Abgr gung va obgu gur ahzore 33 ersref gb gur nafjre bs nabgure pyhr.)

I saw what the 33 meant, but happily missed the wordplay in 32. Thanks for your help with 21, which I couldn't see at all.
